# .toCharArray method not having properties of an array

Tags: java, arrays

This code keeps giving me an error in line 7:

```
error: array required, but String found
           switch(str[i]){
```

It seems to not be treating the array created as an array... any suggestions?

```
public class Encryption_plus_some{

    public String encrypt(String str){
        String answer = "";
        str.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            switch(str[i]){
                case "a": answer += "a";
                    break;
                case "b": answer += "y";
                    break;
                case "c": answer += "x";
                    break;
                case "d": answer += "w";
                    break;
                case "e": answer += "e";
                    break;
                case "f": answer += "u";
                    break;
                case "g": answer += "t";
                    break;
                case "h": answer += "s";
                    break;
                case "i": answer += "i";
                    break;
                case "j": answer += "q";
                    break;
                case "k": answer += "p";
                    break;
                case "l": answer += "o";
                    break;
                case "m": answer += "n";
                    break;
                case "n": answer += "m";
                    break;
                case "o": answer += "o";
                    break;
                case "p": answer += "k";
                    break;
                case "q": answer += "j";
                    break;
                case "r": answer += "i";
                    break;
                case "s": answer += "h";
                    break;
                case "t": answer += "g";
                    break;
                case "u": answer += "u";
                    break;
                case "v": answer += "e";
                    break;
                case "w": answer += "d";
                    break;
                case "x": answer += "c";
                    break;
                case "y": answer += "i";
                    break;
                case "z": answer += "a";
                    break;
                default: answer += " ";
                    break;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(encrypt("some words to encrypt"));   
    }
}
```

Comment: Java Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.toCharArray returns a char array (char[]) from the string, it doesn't turn the String value into a charArray. The String str is still a string.

Try:

```
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

functions can't change the type of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Save your str.toCharArray in a char array

```
char arr[]=str.toCharArray
```

Comment: Please use a valid Java syntax.